# Why StringBuilder throws NullPointerException

Tags: java

This question may be redundant but I really don't understand why the following code throws: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`

```
public class NewClass {
    static StringBuilder SB;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SB.append("Tesing");
        System.out.println(SB);
    }

}
```

Comment: because you don't initialize it...

Comment: What else should it do? You're not initializing it with a `StringBuilder` object, so the variable remains `null`.

Comment: should I initialize static variables as well ? I thought this is only for local variables.

Comment: You need to initialize every object type variable/constant (this is every type that isn't a primitive, like `int`, `float` or `boolean` (mind the lowercase first letter)) at some point or it will remain `null`.

Answer (score 4):

```
SB = new StringBuilder();
```

You missed this part!

Comment: Thank you. You are right

Answer (score 2):

You haven't assigned the `SB` (shouldn't be capitalised btw) variable, so it is still `null` when you attempt call a method on it.

```
public class NewClass {
    // Assignment added below
    static StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sb.append("Tesing");
        System.out.println(sb);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize your StringBuilder. Change it to
`static StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();` and it should work.